# multimap with custom keys - comparison function

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap, comparison-operators

```
bool operator<(const Binding& b1, const Binding& b2)
{
    if(b1.r != b2.r && b1.t1 != b2.t1)
    {
        if(b1.r != b2.r)
            return b1.r < b2.r;
        return b1.t1 < b2.t1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have a comparison function like above. Basically, I need to deem the objects equal if one of their attribute matches. I am using this comparison function for my multimap whose key is 'Binding' object.
The problem I face is that lower_bound and upper_bound functions return the same iterator which points to a valid object. For example (t1 = 1, r = 2) is already in the map and when I try to search it in the map with (t1 = 1, r = 2), I get a same iterator as return value of upper_bound and lower_bound functions.

Is anything wrong with the comparison function? Is there a way to figure a function where I can still ensure that the objects are equivalent even if just one of their field matches?
Shouldn't the upper_bound iterator return the object past the

Comment: The comparison needs to be a *strict weak ordering*. What you describe doesn't sound like one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparator for a map or multimap is expected to express a *strict weak ordering* relation between the set of keys. Your requirement "two objects are equivalent if just one of their fields matches" cannot be such a relation. Take these three keys:

```
1: r=1, t1=10
2: r=1, t1=42
3: r=2, t1=42
```

clearly, keys 1 and 2 are equivalent, because they have the same `r`. Likewise, 2 and 3 are equivalent because of the same `t1`. That means, that 1 and 3 have to be equivalent as well, although they have no matching fields.

As a corollary, *all* possible keys have to be equivalent under these circumstances, which means you dont have any ordering at all and a multimap is not the right way to go.

For your case, Boost.MultiIndex comes to mind. You could then have two separate indices for `r` and `t1` and do your `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `equal_range` searches over both indices separately.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparision function after removing redundant code can be re-written as

```
bool operator<(const Binding& b1, const Binding& b2)
{
    if(b1.r != b2.r && b1.t1 != b2.t1)
    {
        //if(b1.r != b2.r) // always true
            return b1.r < b2.r;
        //return b1.t1 < b2.t1;  // Never reached
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or by de-morgan's law

```
bool operator<(const Binding& b1, const Binding& b2)
{
    if(b1.r == b2.r || b1.t1 == b2.t1) return false;
    else return b1.r < b2.r;
}
```

This does not guarantee `a < c` if `a < b` and `b < c`

Ex: Binding(r, t): a(3, 5), b(4, 6), c(5, 5)

If your comparision function doesn't follow above crieteria, you may get strange results. (including infinite loops in some cases if library is not robust)

Comment: what would be a good data structure in this case when I want to have the objects equivalent even if one of the keys is equal

Comment: As [Arne Mertz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240275/multimap-with-custom-keys-comparison-function/25240490#25240490) suggested in his answer, Boost.MultiIndex is a good choice if it fits in your requirement. One more alternative would be to keep two separate multimaps where comparision function of 1 uses `r` only and other one uses `t` comparision only. Then you can find the range in both of them and use intersection set (min) for all keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison function will return false if either the `r`s or the `t`s match because of the `&&` in the if() clause. Did you mean `||` ? Replacing the `&&` with `||` would give you a valid comparison function which compare first by the `r` field then the `t` field.

Note that `std::pair` already has a comparison function that does exactly that.

Your text below your code though states:

> Basically, I need to deem the objects equal if one of their attribute matches

You cannot do that as it wouldn't be transitive (thus you wouldn't have strict ordering).

The inside of your `if` block has another `if` that is certain to be true, as the `&&` clause means both sides are true.

Comment: The comparison would not be "valid" in the sense that the standard requires comparators to express a strict weak ordering, which would not be the case here (see the other answers)

Comment: Yes of course it is not strict ordering it is mentioned there. I just questioned whether the poster meant || because && makes no sense